# Тесты или исключения в С++? Или все вместе?

Tags: c++, исключения, юнит-тесты

Всем привет! Покоряю С++ и клепаю свое первое "серьезное" приложение. Как это должно быть в идеале, хочу обложить его полностью юнит-тестами. И хотелось бы прояснить, существует ли возможность автоматических тестов для пользовательского ввода? Или здесь только exception в помощь? Всем спасибо

Comment: Исключения и модульные тест не ортогональные понятия, поэтому применение к ним слова «или» мне не ясно.

Comment: Тесты можно написать и на то, что функция бросит исключения при определенных входных параметрах ...

Comment: То, что вы пытаетесь сделать, наверное, подходит под категорию "проверка правильности входных параметров функций".